# String truncation exception in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have a problem with entity framework.
When i build a dynamic lambda expression as bellow :

```
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> where = x => (Constant.STR_BLANK.Equals(imei) || x.Imei.Contains(imei) ) &&
                                                         (Constant.STR_BLANK.Equals(productName) || x.ProductName.Equals(productName)) &&
                                                         (categoryID == -1 || x.CategoryID == categoryID) &&
                                                         (Constant.STR_BLANK.Equals(shopName) || x.ShopName.Equals(shopName)) &&
                                                         (x.DateImport >= start && x.DateImport <= end);
```

when i pass value for imei or productName or any string parameter, i got error :

```
InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
   HResult=-2146233079
   Message=p__linq__0 : String truncation: max=0, len=1, value='3'.
   Source=System.Data.SqlServerCe
```

entity :

```
public class Product
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string ShopName { get; set; }

    public int CountWarranty { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Imei { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateImport { get; set; }

    public int Status { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I found many thread same this problem but i can't fix this error. Any one can help me. Sorry for my english is not good. Thank.